# Join two tables return unique KeyID

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE SETTINGS
   ([AccountNumber] int, [KeyID] int, [KeyValue] varchar(50))
;

INSERT INTO SETTINGS
   ([AccountNumber], [KeyID], [KeyValue])
      VALUES 
      (null, 1, 'welcome'),
      (null, 2, 'defaultaccount'),
      (null, 3, 'greetings'),
      (1234567, 2,'customaccount');
;
```

[image]

What I'm trying to accomplish is to return rows with unique `KeyID`. There will be cases where I will have same `KeyID` appearing twice, but for one row `AccountNumber` will not be null. In this case, I want to return the row where `AccountNumber` is not null.

Output I'm trying to get:

[image]

To get the output I created a `rownumber` for each record and then tried to join the table where `rownumber=1`. But I don't know how to exclude the row where `KeyID`'s match but `AccountNumber is null`.

Here is my code.

```
;WITH singleRow AS (
 SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY KEYID ORDER BY KEYID) as rownum
 FROM SETTINGS);

 SELECT s.KeyID FROM SETTINGS s
   JOIN singleRow r
   ON  s.keyid = r.keyid
   AND r.rownum = 1
```

Should I be using two temp tables in this scenario? In first temp table store all the rows with unique `KeyID` where `AccountNumber is null`. And in the second one store just the row where `AccountNumber is not null`. And then join back the tables? It seems that I'm overcomplicating this.

Here is [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dca65/47).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dca65/55/0)**

```
;WITH singleRows AS 
 (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY keyid ORDER BY AccountNumber DESC)
      AS rownum
    FROM settings
 )
SELECT [AccountNumber], [KeyID], [KeyValue]
FROM singleRows
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you. I see my problem now.

Answer (score 0):

select * from (
SELECT Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY keyid ORDER BY AccountNumber DESC) rnk,*
      AS rownum
    FROM settings ) t where t.rnk=1